# Updating matrix in mpi fortran

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I am running the following mpi fortran code where I generate a matrix in each processor. Then each matrix value is incremented by one and the updated matrix sent to the root processor. Finally, the full matrix is printed after assembling. I am facing a problem in the root processor, where the matrix does not get updated. Why is that? Run the code using four processors to better understand my problem.

```
    PROGRAM MAIN
    include "mpif.h"
    parameter (nx = 4)
    parameter (ny = 4)
    parameter (tsteps = 5)
    real*8    a(nx,ny),b(nx,ny)
    integer   rows,cols
    integer   myid, myid1,Root,source,numprocs
    integer   it,comm2d,ierr,req
    integer   sx, ex, sy, ey
    integer   dims(2),coord(2)
    logical   periods(2)
    integer status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
    data periods/2*.false./

    Root = 0
    CALL MPI_INIT( ierr )
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myid1,ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numprocs,ierr)
c       Get a new communicator for a decomposition of the domain.  
c       Let MPI find a "good" decomposition
    dims(1) = 0
    dims(2) = 0
    CALL MPI_DIMS_CREATE(numprocs,2,dims,ierr)
    if (myid1.EQ.Root) then
        print *,'dimensions:',dims(1),dims(2)
    endif
    CALL MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,2,dims,periods,.true.,
     &                    comm2d,ierr)
c       Get my position in this communicator
c       CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(comm2d,myid,ierr)
c       Compute the decomposition
    CALL fnd2ddecomp(comm2d,nx,ny,sx,ex,sy,ey)
    rows = ex-sx+1 
    cols = ey-sy+1  
c       Initialize the a matrix
    do  i= sx,ex
        do j=sy,ey
          a(i,j) = (i-1)+(j-1)
        enddo
    enddo    
    do it = 1,tsteps 
       do  i= sx,ex
           do j=sy,ey
              a(i,j) = a(i,j)+1
           enddo
       enddo
C     Send the results to other processors      
    call MPI_ISEND(sx,1,MPI_INTEGER,Root,1, 
     &                   comm2d,req,ierr)
    call MPI_ISEND(ex,1,MPI_INTEGER,Root,1, 
     &                   comm2d,req,ierr)
    call MPI_ISEND(sy,1,MPI_INTEGER,Root,1, 
     &                   comm2d,req,ierr)
    call MPI_ISEND(ey,1,MPI_INTEGER,Root,1, 
     &                   comm2d,req,ierr)
    call MPI_ISEND(a(sx:ex,sy:ey),cols*rows,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
     &                   Root,1,comm2d,req,ierr )
c    Recieved the results from othe precessors   
    if (myid1.EQ.Root) then
       do source = 0,numprocs-1
          call MPI_RECV(sx,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
     &                   1,comm2d,status,ierr )
          call MPI_RECV(ex,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
     &                   1,comm2d,status,ierr )
          call MPI_RECV(sy,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
     &                   1,comm2d,status,ierr )
          call MPI_RECV(ey,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
     &                   1,comm2d,status,ierr )
          call MPI_RECV(a(sx:ex,sy:ey),cols*rows,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 
     &                   source,1,comm2d,status,ierr)
          a(sx:ex,sy:ey) = a(sx:ex,sy:ey) 
          call MPI_Wait(req, status, ierr) 
       enddo
       endif
       if (myid1.EQ.Root) then
c      print the results
       print *, 'time step=',it
        do 90 i=1,nx
          do 80 j = 1,ny
             write(*,70)a(i,j)
  70        format(2x,f8.2,$)
  80      continue
          print *, ' '
  90    continue      
       endif
     enddo
C      Cleanup goes here.
      CALL MPI_Comm_free( comm2d, ierr )
30    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

      STOP
      END
C******************************************************* 
      subroutine fnd2ddecomp(comm2d,nx,ny,sx,ex,sy,ey)
      integer   comm2d
      integer   nx,ny,sx,ex,sy,ey
      integer   dims(2),coords(2),ierr
      logical   periods(2)
c Get (i,j) position of a processor from Cartesian topology.
      CALL MPI_Cart_get(comm2d,2,dims,periods,coords,ierr)
C Decomposition in first (ie. X) direction
      CALL MPE_DECOMP1D(nx,dims(1),coords(1),sx,ex)
C Decomposition in second (ie. Y) direction
      CALL MPE_DECOMP1D(ny,dims(2),coords(2),sy,ey)
      return
      end
c********************************************************************* 
      SUBROUTINE MPE_DECOMP1D(n,numprocs,myid,s,e)
      integer n,numprocs,myid,s,e,nlocal,deficit
      nlocal  = n / numprocs
      s       = myid * nlocal + 1
      deficit = mod(n,numprocs)
      s       = s + min(myid,deficit)
C Give one more slice to processors
      if (myid .lt. deficit) then
          nlocal = nlocal + 1
      endif
      e = s + nlocal - 1
      if (e .gt. n .or. myid .eq. numprocs-1) e = n
      return
      end
```

I am generating the following matrix:

```
   A=[0     1     2     3
     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     6] ;
```

I am updating matrix A by adding 1 in a loop, sending, receiving A in parts and printing on desktop. A(1:2,1:2) is not showing any update on printing the matrix.

Run the code with four processors for better understanding my problem.

Comment: *"Run the code using four processors for better understanding my problem."* While it is very nice to have a reproduction code, a proper problem description should also include the **expected output** of the program, the **current output** of the program and some short explanation why the current output is considered wrong.

Comment: I have included the matrix and included some explanation.

Comment: I don't see ani MPI_Wait() in your program. MPI_ISend() does not have to send anything.

Comment: And even worse, you should use collectives and not point 2 point sends/receives. Read about MPI_Gather() and MPI_Scatter().

Comment: @VladimirF MPI_ISEND is sending 2x2 submatrices of A to Roots processor 0. I have used MPI_Wait, though the result is same.   I am aware of MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather, if I want to send and receive 6000x6000 matrix, which one would be fast? MPI_Send/Recieve or MPI_Scatter/Gather?

Comment: MPI_ISend without MPI_Wait typically does not do anything at all. The wait is obligatory. The collectives should be faster.

Comment: I used mpi_wait, still the Root 0 sub matrix shows no update for each time step. Where as if I print the matrix after once after all the time steps, it is showing updated matrix which is correct.

Comment: You must first wait and then print. Cannot say more without the code.

Comment: I agree, that's what the documentation too says. But when I place mpi_wait after mpi_isend, there is no response, I think it went to dead lock or infinite loop kind of.

Comment: Just tried with mpi_irecv...same dead lock..

Comment: Just use Gather and Scatter and learn IRecv and ISend from smaller examples...

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake in the code. The indices sx,ex,sy,ey when sending to Root are being over written and thus it was not getting updated. I have corrected the code and posting below.

```
PROGRAM MAIN
    include "mpif.h"
    parameter (nx = 4)
    parameter (ny = 4)
    parameter (tsteps = 5)
    real*8    a(nx,ny),b(nx,ny)
    integer   rows,cols
    integer   myid, myid1,Root,source,numprocs
    integer   it,comm2d,ierr,req
    integer   sx, ex, sy, ey
    integer   sx0, ex0, sy0, ey0
    integer   dims(2),coord(2)
    logical   periods(2)
    integer status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
    data periods/2*.false./

    Root = 0
    CALL MPI_INIT( ierr )
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myid1,ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numprocs,ierr)
c       Get a new communicator for a decomposition of the domain.  
c       Let MPI find a "good" decomposition
    dims(1) = 0
    dims(2) = 0
    CALL MPI_DIMS_CREATE(numprocs,2,dims,ierr)
    if (myid1.EQ.Root) then
        print *,'dimensions:',dims(1),dims(2)
    endif
    CALL MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,2,dims,periods,.true.,
     &                    comm2d,ierr)
c       Get my position in this communicator
c       CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(comm2d,myid,ierr)
c       Compute the decomposition
    CALL fnd2ddecomp(comm2d,nx,ny,sx,ex,sy,ey)
    rows = ex-sx+1 
    cols = ey-sy+1  
c       Initialize the a matrix
    do  i= sx,ex
        do j=sy,ey
          a(i,j) = (i-1)+(j-1)
        enddo
    enddo    
    do it = 1,tsteps 
       do  i= sx,ex
           do j=sy,ey
              a(i,j) = a(i,j)+1
           enddo
       enddo
C     Send the results to other processors      
    call MPI_ISEND(sx,1,MPI_INTEGER,Root,1, 
     &                   comm2d,req,ierr)
    call MPI_ISEND(ex,1,MPI_INTEGER,Root,1, 
     &                   comm2d,req,ierr)
    call MPI_ISEND(sy,1,MPI_INTEGER,Root,1, 
     &                   comm2d,req,ierr)
    call MPI_ISEND(ey,1,MPI_INTEGER,Root,1, 
     &                   comm2d,req,ierr)
    call MPI_ISEND(a(sx:ex,sy:ey),cols*rows,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
     &                   Root,1,comm2d,req,ierr )
c    Recieved the results from othe precessors   
    if (myid1.EQ.Root) then
       do source = 0,numprocs-1
          call MPI_RECV(sx0,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
     &                   1,comm2d,status,ierr )
          call MPI_RECV(ex0,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
     &                   1,comm2d,status,ierr )
          call MPI_RECV(sy0,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
     &                   1,comm2d,status,ierr )
          call MPI_RECV(ey0,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
     &                   1,comm2d,status,ierr )
          call MPI_RECV(a(sx0:ex0,sy0:ey0),cols*rows,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 
     &                   source,1,comm2d,status,ierr)
          a(sx0:ex0,sy0:ey0) = a(sx0:ex0,sy0:ey0) 
          call MPI_Wait(req, status, ierr) 
       enddo
       endif
       if (myid1.EQ.Root) then
c      print the results
       print *, 'time step=',it
        do 90 i=1,nx
          do 80 j = 1,ny
             write(*,70)a(i,j)
  70        format(2x,f8.2,$)
  80      continue
          print *, ' '
  90    continue      
       endif
     enddo
C      Cleanup goes here.
      CALL MPI_Comm_free( comm2d, ierr )
30    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

      STOP
      END
C******************************************************* 
      subroutine fnd2ddecomp(comm2d,nx,ny,sx,ex,sy,ey)
      integer   comm2d
      integer   nx,ny,sx,ex,sy,ey
      integer   dims(2),coords(2),ierr
      logical   periods(2)
c Get (i,j) position of a processor from Cartesian topology.
      CALL MPI_Cart_get(comm2d,2,dims,periods,coords,ierr)
C Decomposition in first (ie. X) direction
      CALL MPE_DECOMP1D(nx,dims(1),coords(1),sx,ex)
C Decomposition in second (ie. Y) direction
      CALL MPE_DECOMP1D(ny,dims(2),coords(2),sy,ey)
      return
      end
c********************************************************************* 
      SUBROUTINE MPE_DECOMP1D(n,numprocs,myid,s,e)
      integer n,numprocs,myid,s,e,nlocal,deficit
      nlocal  = n / numprocs
      s       = myid * nlocal + 1
      deficit = mod(n,numprocs)
      s       = s + min(myid,deficit)
C Give one more slice to processors
      if (myid .lt. deficit) then
          nlocal = nlocal + 1
      endif
      e = s + nlocal - 1
      if (e .gt. n .or. myid .eq. numprocs-1) e = n
      return
      end
```

Comment: This code cannot be correct. The wait must not be inside  the `if` as I have commented long time ago below the question. The wait belongs to the Isends, not to the Recvs.